# node.js & forever not recognized?

Tags: node.js, forever

I have a question about running node.js and forever.

It seems that when I type in my console forever start, nothing is being done. It simply shows the new line in console, as if I pressed enter without any command at all. And if I type eg "dsad" then I get an error about uknown command.

Interesting thing is that node.js scripts aren't executed with "node" commmand, but with "nodejs" command. So, scripts that are executed via "nodejs" command do run, but when I type node "..." it just shows the new line in console, the same as when I tried to run a forever command.

Tried to reinstall forever, also with -g but no luck. Anyone experienced similiar problems?!

Tnx!

Comment: What command are you entering to start forever?

Comment: which is your linux distribution? Ubuntu?

Comment: my linux distribution is ubuntu server!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to start forever first, then start node app.js using forever command:

```
forever app.js
```

Check forever --help for more details.

```
forever --help
```

Comment: tnx, it seems that my problem is in different nature, since I type in forever --help, and I don't get any output of it, it just enters a new line in command (as I said, as if I just pressed enter without any command at all)

Comment: Looks forever is not installed, If installed, May be upto application.

Comment: Check, is forever is installed OR not by using command: "npm list forever"

Comment: You can installed again globally-> "npm install forever -g"

Comment: "May be upto application." ? 
Btw, interesting thing is that my console doesn't return "Uknown command" after I run forever (...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43575/discussion-between-pravin-mishra-and-adrian)